# How to generate weekly dates from bi-weekly pay period in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to convert bi-weekly pay period to weekly dates. Lets say I have `3/2/2012`, `3/16/2012`, `3/30/2012` and some gaps and then again biweekly dates.

generate 
`3/9/2012`, `3/16/2012`, `3/23/2012`, `3/30/2012` and so on...I was trying to use `INDEX` and `MATCH` but it would give me biweekly again. The perfect way would be to match and generate weeks from my randomized biweekly dates. 
Here is an example of my worksheet: 
[image]

Comment: If `A1` contains the date `3/2/2012`, using the formula `=A1+7` does not help?

Comment: @Hauke P. but then I have random bi-weekly dates with some gaps between them.

Comment: Could you give an outline of how your original worksheet looks like? It's hard to give an answer without knowing your current data situation.

Comment: @Hauke P. uploaded it! :)

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a way to automatically add new rows so that the resulting table will not contain be-weekly but weekly dates?

Comment: @Hauke P. Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get a new column of weekly dates in P2 down based on the bi-weekly dates you already have in I2 down

Put this formula in P2

`=INDEX(I$2:I$1000,(ROWS(P$2:P2)+1)/2)`

and this formula in P3

`=IF(P2>0,P2+7,0)`

Format both of those cells with this custom format

m/d/yyyy;;

make sure you include the two semi-colons at the end

Now select both P2 and P3 and drag down the column until you get blanks

Comment: Thank you! I like this thinking! It's be ideal if it had unique weekly dates without any duplicates! Any thought? This is the outcome I have so far: `10/15/2010
10/22/2010
10/29/2010
11/5/2010
11/12/2010
11/12/2010
11/19/2010
11/26/2010
12/3/2010
12/10/2010
12/23/2010
12/30/2010
1/21/2011
1/28/2011
6/24/2011
6/24/2011
7/1/2011
7/8/2011`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's how to accomplish this:

1. Create a new sheet.
2. Select column K and apply date data type formatting.
3. In cell K2, enter this formula: (Replace Sheet1 with the name of the worksheet with your data).

   ```
   =IF(MOD(ROW(K2),2)=1,K1+7,INDIRECT("Sheet1!R"&(1+(ROW(K2))/2)&"C"&COLUMN(K2),FALSE))
   ```
4. Drag this formula across the sheet as much as you need to.

The formula uses the `INDIRECT` function to calculate the location of the cell where it should get the data from.

If you need the cells in other columns to be blank, replace the equivalent for `K1+7` in the formula with `""`.

Last but not least... while this formula works, here here's a warning about this method: The `INDIRECT` function is be pretty slow - so there might be some performance issues if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Thanks! It is giving me weekly date based on the bi-weekly pay period I have but the weeks are very randomly put and I can't sort them.

Comment: Phew, that'll be pretty complex. Let's hope you'll get other answers.